# C# Windows Service - Start .exe from App.config

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer

I use the below code to execute a .exe file from Windows Service.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Right now, I hard coded the path as @'C:\Program Files\Server\Test.exe'
It is working fine.

Now, I want to avoid the hard coding. When I just use Test.exe, it goes to C:\Windows\System32.

How can I dynamically get the installed path from windows service? Or how can I read path from App.config file ?

Comment: Sure you can read a configuration value containing the path from your services App.config file.

Comment: If the other exe is deployed in the same folder as your servide I'd recommend avoid putting such information in a configuration file.   The latter is just going to lead to extra maintenance when the information is best gleamed at runtime automatically as per **tinudu's** (for example) answer below

Comment: @MickyD For the path, I used tinud's cdeo.  I have also Thread.Sleep(minutes), as polling interval. How can I read the 'minutes' from App.config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Comment: Perfectly worked by your single line code. Any idea about reading App.config file without error from Windows Service.

Comment: In App.config: `<configuration><appSettings><add key="bla" value="quack"/></...`, in C#: `var bla = (string)new AppSettingsReader().GetValue("bla", typeof(string)); // quack`.

Comment: I am getting `Configuration system failed to initialize` error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're .net all the way down (i.e. your Windows Service is a .net application) then you can use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) (from the System.Reflection namespace):

```
var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
var launchLocation = entryAssembly.Location;
```

Alternatively you can check the [`AppDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) you're executing in (assuming you're not doing anything clever with multiple of them!)

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var launchLocation = appDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

A simple Console App:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var launchLocationFromAssembly = entryAssembly.Location;


    var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    var launchLocationFromAppDomain = appDomain.BaseDirectory;

    Console.WriteLine(launchLocationFromAssembly);
    Console.WriteLine(launchLocationFromAppDomain);
}
```

Gives the following output:

> c:\users\robertwray\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe
>
> c:\users\robertwray\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\bin\Debug\

This means that if you did use the `Assembly` to retrieve the path, you'd need to strip off the name of the executable with something like:

```
var launchPathFromAssembly = Path.GetDirectoryName(launchLocationFromAssembly);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```